# Update specific bin/column and not all in Table/set in Aerospike

Tags: go, aerospike

I have following struct -

```
type User struct {
    ID string `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
    Password string `json:"passwprd"`
    Confirmed int `json:"confirmed"`
    ConfirmCode string `json:"confirmcode"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}
```

Now, Whenever I am inserting data, all is fine, But whenever I update a specific bin `Confirmed` & `ConfirmCode`, my all other data is replaced with blank value too.

Here is the code, I am using for an update -

```
t := time.Now()
u := User{
    Confirmed: 1,
    UpdatedAt: t,
}
key, err := as.NewKey("foobar", "users", "1")
if err != nil {
    ctx.StatusCode(iris.StatusBadRequest)
    ctx.JSON(map[string]string{"error": "Can't update key! Try again " + err.Error()})
    return
}
err = client.PutObject(nil, key, &u)
if err != nil {
    ctx.StatusCode(iris.StatusBadRequest)
    ctx.JSON(map[string]string{"error": "Can't Update object! Try again" + err.Error()})
    return
}
```

As you can see, While doing Update, I am only providing 2 fields of the struct.

**Doing this, it erases all old existing data except the above 2 used for update above.**

Do I need to provide "Old value" again while doing the update too in Aerospike?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the RecordExistsAction Policy:  https://godoc.org/github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go#RecordExistsAction

You should be able to use UPDATE (default) which is "update or insert" unless you have overwritten it with REPLACE?